# Capture image form a IP CAMERA

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have a IP camera, i need to capture the image from it.

I have no idea how to do this is Vb.net 2010

Please help me. in simple code

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture frames from IP camera using EmguCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253764/capture-frames-from-ip-camera-using-emgucv)

Answer (score 0):

The DevExpress CameraControl displays a video stream from a video capture device (a webcam) and allows you to save snapshots.

https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114582/controls-and-libraries/editors-and-simple-controls/camera-control

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).